# Selecting suitable database for analytics data

Tags: database, bigdata, hbase, analytics, aggregation

We need to create enterprise product and need to select the storage option for analytics data, initially data will be in tb's(10-40tb) but in coming years could go up to few PB's.
Requirements:

- high aggregation speed.
- suitable for real-time analytics.
- timescale db.
- it should be easy to scale.
- there should not be any licensing fees.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I am not very aware of timescale, but I will try to answer.

From what I read, this is an add-on for postgresql. You can go for any cloud solution offered for Postgres, scaling should not be a problem as you can shard the DB, and for example for azure Flexible server is great where you can choose Burstable scaling in options (very useful for cost cutting):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/how-to-scale-compute-storage-portal

What might be a problem eventually is that storage is somewhat capped, and this might not be ideal for PB-scale. However, it can be tried with higher resource SKUs offered such as 20 Vcores on 32 TB storage. As you reach PB scale, you need to distribute between multiple Postgres Flexible's or find another solution. In Azure for example, there was an option of scaling SQL Servers in a big data cluster based on Kubernetes, but this is not available to other DB vendors AFAIK. If I didnt have the requirement of Timescale, I would just go with Synapse(MPP) where you can scale Exabytes, and it is the true solution to big data without bothering with increased complexity in your architecture.

For limits of this setup :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/postgresql/flexible-server/concepts-limits

Regarding your other requirement for real-time analytics, I am not sure how suitable it would be, but the DB should handle the stream well at least up until a certain velocity, which is not something I would worry about

Answer (score 0):

Full disclosure, I work for Imply.

[Apache Druid](https://druid.apache.org) offers the features you are looking for.
It was specifically designed for high concurrency, fast OLAP queries on TBs to PBs of event data. It partitions the data on time and along other dimensions, parallelizes query execution and data ingestion. It provides query on arrival for streaming ingestion with typically <1s latencies. Druid queries seamlessly combine history and real-time streaming data. It has been [implemented by many organizations](https://druid.apache.org/druid-powered/) for both its interactive and real-time analytic capabilities.